Catalan's constant as continued fraction
I believe I found an infinite alternate continued fraction that represents Catalan's constant :

$$G=1-\cfrac{\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}+ \cfrac{1}{1- \cfrac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+ \cfrac{1}{1- \cfrac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\cfrac{2}{ 1-\cfrac{2 }{\frac{1}{2}+\cfrac{2}{ 1-\cfrac{2 }{ \frac{1}{2}+\cfrac{3}{ 1-\cfrac{3 }{ \frac{1}{2}+\cfrac{3}{ 1-\cfrac{3 }{\ddots}}}}}}}}}}}}}$$

Here is PARI/GP code.
I am looking for a hint on how to prove this conjecture.

I'm trying to understand the equivalence of the continued fraction and the PARI/GP code. Why does the PARI/GP code always initially set $a=1$ when $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{(x \bmod 2)}$ alternates between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$?

@StevenClark $a=1$ is just a random initial value ; taking $a=2$ or $3$ would give the same final value, because of so much iterations. The PARI/GP code exactly follows the described continued fraction. It applies first the $n$ numerator, then the $n-1$ numerator, etc, down to the $1$ numerator at the beginning of the continued fractiion.

When terminated, its important that your PARI/GP code exactly match the termination of the continued fraction at the corresponding point when comparing to other representations. I believe your PARI/GP code currently only matches then $n$ is odd which was enough for me to discover the conjectured relationship in the answer I posted below. Do you not consider the answer I posted below to be a hint on how to prove your conjecture, or are you really looking for a rigorous and complete proof of your conjecture?

I believe your PARI/GP code evaluated at $n=2 k-1$ is equivalent to the continued fraction
$$C=1-\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{3+\frac{4}{1+\frac{4}{3+\frac{16}{1+\frac{16}{3+\frac{36}{1+\frac{36}{3+\ldots}}}}}}}\tag{1}$$
for the Catalan constant $C$ found here on the Wolfram Functions Site.

I believe some clarification is needed since the evaluation of the continued fraction $C$ in (1) above needs to be terminated slightly differently than the way the PARI/GP code is terminating the evaluation of the continued fraction $G$ in the question. Also, the PARI/GP code needs to be corrected for termination at even values of $n$.

I believe the continued fraction in $G$ the question above can be evaluated as
$$G_n=g_n\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{(n+1) \bmod 2}\right)\tag{2}$$
where $g_n(a)$ is defined recursively as
$$g_n(a)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 g_{n-1}\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n \bmod 2}+\frac{(-1)^{(n+1) \bmod 2}\, \left\lceil \frac{n}{4}\right\rceil}{a}\right) & n\geq 1 \\
 1-\frac{1}{4 a} & n=0 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}.$$

I believe the continued fraction $C$ in (1) above can be evaluated as
$$C_n=c_{n-1}((2 n+1) \bmod 4)\tag{4}$$
where $c_n(a)$ is defined recursively as
$$c_n(a)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
c_{n-1}\left(((2 n+1) \bmod 4)+\frac{\left(2 \left\lceil \frac{n}{2}\right\rceil \right)^2}{a}\right) & n\geq 1 \\
 1-\frac{1}{2 a} & n=0 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{5}.$$

Using formulas (2) to (4) above, I've verified $G_{2 k-1}=C_k$ for $1\le k\le 500$. Notice $g_n(\ldots)$ in formula (2) above versus $c_{n-1}(\ldots)$ in formula (4) above which clarifies the difference in how the two continued fractions must be terminated for the stated equivalence $G_{2 k-1}=C_k$.
